# Smallest, Non-zero Eigevalue of a Sparse Hermitian Matrix Using Matlab's Eigs

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

I'm looking for the first $10$ smallest non-zero eigenvalue in a symmetrical, sparse, hermitian Matrix $A_{3000 \times 3000}$. There are also a lot of zero-eigenvalues in the eigenvalue-spectrum which are not of interest.

Matlab's **eigs** lets me define a sigma (starting point), but the result always gives me some zero-eigenvalues along with my needed eigevalues. (my `sigma=1e2`).
Does someone know how to define this sigma in eigs (or some other function) which allows me to get **N** eigenvalues higher then my defined sigma?

Answer (score 0):

Naive algorithm that could work.

```
N=10;
(n,m)=size(A);
assert(n==m)
p =sprank(A);
d = eigs(A,n-p+N,'sm');
d=d(d>sigma);
```

*Note*

`eig` need $O(n^3)$ for $n\times n$ matrix, I guess `sprank` is much faster(I don't know though)  and `eigs` uses [Lanczos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm#Iteration) algorithm, which should cost $O(n^2)$, so I think it is still better then $eig$ even for large p.

---

U can try to [remove the singularity](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/108835-how-to-get-only-linearly-independent-rows-in-a-matrix-or-to-remove-linear-dependency-b-w-rows-in-a-m) of your matrix, but I guess it won't be much more effective.

Comment: thanks, but as you can see in my question - I am using **eigs**

Comment: sorry, I mistakenly sent this incomplete answer - will delete in a mo

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/543051)

Comment: @Quintic read the previous comment

Comment: @KoshaMisa instead of deleting I provided some sort of solution

Comment: I think, this costs event more computation time then just using **eig** funciton and then filtering like you did - because in my case i would have about 1200 zero eigenvalues, so eigs would have to find 1210 eigenvalues - this is really not a good idea

Comment: this is why this is a naive algorithm, but see the edit.

Comment: well yes it is - this is really costly.. I have tried and - thanks, but this is unfortunately not a good solution for this task. I think that Jacobi Davidson Method should be much better, then Lanczos but eigs doesn't seem to use it. Is there any good Jacobi Davidson implementation?

Comment: JD require strongly diagonally dominant matrix, is your matrix satisfies this condition? Also I'm not sure it is much more efficient. 
anyway, 1) http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter11.pdf

2) http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~bai/ET/jacobi_davidson_methods/jacobi_davidson_methods.html

Comment: yes - my matrix satisfies this condition! But again - using **eigs**: if I find the right sigma, then everything works fine and the computation time for 10 Egenvalues is like 1 sec - I think the problem with the **sigma** of **eigs** is that it searches for eigenvalues around the **sigma** and not starting from the sigma and counting up or down. Would you know how to make the algorithm "search up" , starting from the lowest eigevalue defined by sigma?

Comment: try to read about deflation algorithms, e.g. http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/IFEM.d/IFEM.AppE.d/IFEM.AppE.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32924/discussion-between-kosha-misa-and-michael-medvinsky).